# Rails - Figaro gem - how can I add a collaborator to my repo without sharing application.yml variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, figaro-ruby

I am using rails 5 with figaro gem to manage my environment variables.

I have just started working with a coding coach, who is setting up my repo on his system.

Is there a way for me to share my repo (so that he can configure it) without giving him the codes in my application.yml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `application.yml` to git ignore. If the file is already commited in git history, you can follow instruction in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1274057/2912211) to let git 'forget' it completely.

Comment: But how can he use the application if he doesnt have the file

Comment: You can tell him/her personally those ENV variables, so they can be set directly. But I guess those ENV variables you are afraid to share are external services credentials, usually these services would provide another set of credentials for you to test (staging/sandbox), you can share this to your coding coach, so it won't affect your production env.